# List of Tezos block explorers

Tags: blockexplorer, tzstats

A few days ago I couldn't access the block explorer I regularly use. Does anyone have an alternative one?

Comment: "I just few days ago saw that the website is dead" Which website?

Comment: https://tzstats.com/ seems working

Comment: Most probably a cache problem in the user browser. Have you tried turning if off and on again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a lot of options:

- [TzKT](https://tzkt.io/) - I recommend this one!
- [Tzstats](https://tzstats.com/)
- [Tezblock](https://tezblock.io/)
- [Tezos.id](https://tezos.id/)
- [Better Call Dev](https://better-call.dev/) - for smart contracts
- [Teztracker](https://teztracker.everstake.one/mainnet)
- [Mininax](https://mininax.io/)